# How do I get “in-page analytics” through Google analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I read the "In-page analytics" setting for a property through the API?

I only found it mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=532&q=in-page&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary which is not not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. There is a [resource description for a web property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource-representations) in the documentation for the Management API and it does not include the status for the in-page analysis. And  the link in your post is a feature request, which is another indication that this is currently not possible.